# PostgreSQL postmaster will not start after configuring for SymmetricDS

Tags: postgresql, replication

I'm trying to configure SymmetricDS for use with PostgreSQL, a database platform widely supported by the former.

When running through the [quick-start tutorial](http://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.5/html/tutorial.html#tutorial-install) (which leads you to some [pre-setup documentation](http://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.5/html/databases.html#ap02-postgresql)), I am instructed to append the following line to `postgresql.conf`:

```
custom_variable_classes = 'symmetric'
```

The next step of the tutorial requires the postmaster to be running (at least that's what I glean from the stack trace...), so I

```
service postgresql-9.2 start
```

but this fails.

Without this single line added (or if it's commented out), PostgreSQL starts as expected.

I must be doing something wrong, so what is it?

1. `yum install postgresql92 postgresql92-server`
2. Download and unzip SymmetricDS into `~`
3. `service postgresql-9.2 initdb`
4. Edit `/var/lib/pgsql/9.2/data/postgresql.conf` as above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I must be doing something wrong, so what is it?

Per the 9.2 release notes, `custom_variable_classes` was removed. It is no longer required or supported. You can just leave it out without problems.

Comment: I'm confident this answer is correct, but I'll give you a tick when it works or I give up; whichever comes first :-) Thanks!